# Displaying Excel cell values in a comma-separated list

Tags: excel, formula

I have data in Excel like this:

```
Column1       Column2
NI-Summer-2   parent
NI-548        underneath are child
NI-549
NI-550

NI-Summer-1   parent
NI-421        underneath are child
NI-422
```

I need to add a new column that displays the children in one string joined by commas, like so:

```
Column1      Column2   Column3
NI-Summer-2  parent    NI-Summer-2,NI-548,NI-549,NI-550
NI-548       underneath are child
NI-549
NI-550

NI-Summer-1  parent    NI-421,NI-422
NI-421       underneath are child
NI-422
```

(The values below each parent should be comma-separated in the next column.)

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that is a blank row between entries.

Create two extra columns D and E

In Column E, put this in E1 and copy the formula down:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(A1)),A1,A1&","&E2)
```

In Column D, put this in D1 and copy the formula down:

```
=IF(MID(A1,3,8)="-Summer-",E1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit I'm having difficult understanding your question, but I would recommend using the concatenate function to add a comma to the string you are creating.

For example,

```
AA = CONCATENATE(childcell, ", ", childcell)
```

would give "child, child" as an output in AA.